# how can we establish a connection between two application with http same VM instance in GCP

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, connection, firewall, httpserver

we have two applications running on different ports,

1. application1 is on 8080 and
2. application2 is on 5005.
   We are able to connect to the application1 from browser with external IP and port 8080. (ex: http://:8080.
3. as per design, application1 should connect to application2 on 5005.
4. when we run both with local host it is working fine. But,
5. when we try with external IP from VM Instance (on GCP) we can able to open Page from application 1 but not unable to connect to application 2 from application 1.

Note: Our VM Instance is running on GCP Compute engine.

Could someone help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Google Compute Engine instances do not have a public IP assigned to a network interface. Public IP addresses are assigned to a special 1-to-1 NAT that converts the public IP address to a private IP address. You should either connect on `localhost` or the private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As the other user [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) pointed out, you should use your Internal IP address, or in your case, as both applications are in the same Instance, you could use “localhost”.

However, if you try to use your External IP, keep in mind that you will need to add to your [VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) a [Firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to allow traffic to these ports. In order to do so, [you can follow this guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules), that explains how to add new firewall rules to your VPC network.

Regards.